# Plotting monthly SO2 map

Tags: arcmap, interpolation

I need to plot a map to show monthly SO2 emission point over a specific area. To do so, I have an Excel monthly dataset (derived from satellite data) contains a column for latitude, a column for longitude and a column for SO2 amount. However, when I add XY data on ArcGIS, there are lots of SO2 values for each lat/lon (because satellite scans the area every day, and I add data for 30 days at once).

The problem is that when I use an interpolation tool (kriging), I do not get the right result. How can I sort this problem out? The image I tagged is related to when I add XY data on the map.

Comment: You essentially need to summarize point data at each lat/lon using a statistic such as mean or max? Why are the results not as you expect?

Comment: Do you get error messages? Wildly wrong interpolation values? Interpolation in the wrong place? Have you checked your variogram? Do you want total SO2 emissions, in which case sum the daily values and krige that?

Comment: I did not get an error message once I have done interpolation, but when I compare my result, with the accepted result , my result is not reasonable. I think I should first calculate one single value for each lat and lon then plot the map, and not doing interpolation, cause the data cover all the area. So how can I first give a value to each lat/lon?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your point data is regularly gridded, you can use the [Point Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/point-statistics.htm) tool.

Add your spreadsheet data to ArcMap, use the "Make XY Event Layer (Data Management)" tool then convert/export to a featureclass (i.e a shapefile or file GDB featureclass).

Then use the Point Statistics tool to output a raster where each pixel is the mean of all months for each point.  Make sure you set the output extent to be 1/2 pixel less than the minimum and 1/2 a pixel more than the maximum of your point featureclass extent.

For example with the following dummy data that describe 4 points with 12 months worth of data located at coordinate (1,1), (1,2), (2,2) and (2,1):

```
X, Y, S02, MONTH
1, 1, 2.00, 1
1, 1, 7.00, 2
...
1, 1, 5.00, 11
1, 1, 2.00, 12
2, 1, 8.00, 1
2, 1, 4.00, 2
...
2, 1, 3.00, 11
2, 1, 2.00, 12
2, 2, 6.00, 1
2, 2, 10.00, 2
...
2, 2, 9.00, 11
2, 2, 7.00, 12
1, 2, 9.00, 1
...
1, 2, 6.00, 11
1, 2, 10.00, 12
```

In the tool environment settings I specified processing extent = 0.5,0.5 to 2.5, 2.5 i.e my dummy pixel size is 1, and the featureclass extent is 1,1 to 2,2 so I set the processing extent to be 1/2 a pixel less/more than that.

[image]

**Edit:** err replace "month" in the above with "day"
for each month.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it and it worked. I profoundly appreciate the time you consider to answer my question.

Comment: @seti then please accept my answer by clicking the tick between the voting arrows.